# Generate a random tennis match using two groups of players in google docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need some help with the formulas for a google sheet I'm putting together. In the attached image you can see that I have two groups of players - with 8 players in each group.

I would like to generate or create a match using those 16 players but:

- players from group A can only play with a different player from group A (i.e., not themselves). Same for group B
- The pair from group A plays against the pair from group B. This produces 4 games using all of the players.

In the attached image you can see an example of what I'm looking for in B12:E15.

I'm having issues with the formulas to prevent duplication. I'm using
formulas like =INDEX(A2:A9, RANDBETWEEN(1, 8)) to randomize the player and then a formula such as =INDEX(FILTER(A2:A9, .....) with conditions but I keep getting circular references.

[image]

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out. `the formula is linked to the checkbox` in **Cell_B10** so as to bypass the constant randomization of the output that'll happen due to any edit(s) happening in the sheet. now it exclusively happens on checkbox toggle*

```js
=wraprows(sort(A2:A9,let(Σ,lambda(x,x)(randarray(8)),if(B10,Σ,Σ)),),2)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! That's impressive. I verified it works. It looks like your function is elegantly randomizing the list of players into 2 columns. My example was the simple example with one tennis match but I really need to make sure that in the next match player from Group A doesn't play with the same player from Group A...that's why I was trying to use filter functions and hoping to get that working to expand on the problem.